# php rand() function display negative value

Tags: php, random, numbers, integer, overflow

I have this code for generate a random positive number:

```
$token= rand(12132423534, 9285328457237);
```

Sometimes $token value is a negative number. I think the int value is in overflow, but which is the maximum value for not have this error?

Comment: "*but which is the maximum value for not have this error*" - `var_dump(PHP_INT_MAX);`

Comment: You're probably getting integer overflow. On a 32bit machine this number is significantly lower than on a 64bit machine.

Comment: Yep. 2,147,483,647 is (AFAIK) the largest number than can be stored in 32 bits. For 64 bit, it is (2^63)−1 (which is approx. 9,223,372,036,854,775,807).

Comment: ok, then  what values must have max and min?

Comment: Seems like you are on 32-Bit. So go with a number below `2147483647`

Comment: @AmalMurali to be precise, `2.147.483.647` is the largest integer for 32-bit `long` data type, because from 32 bits one is reserved for sign. But with 32-bit `unsigned long` you can get `2^32-1` max value. However, in PHP `long` is int and it cannot be unsigned (natively).

Answer (score 4):

The maximum value a PHP integer on a 32-bit Machine is `2147483647` . You need the [`GMP Extension`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/gmp.installation.php) for your current scenario.

Comment: XD yes I see this after! Thanks for all!

Answer (score 1):

PHP has `getrandmax()` function specially for detecting maximum possible value returned by rand(). BTW, why don't you using `mt_rand()` (with mt_getrandmax()), which generates better randoms & faster?